# Python list in SQL query as parameter

Tags: python, sql

I have a Python list, say

```
l = [1,5,8]
```

I want to write a SQL query to get the data for all the elements of the list, say

```
select name from students where id = |IN THE LIST l|
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: l1 = ['a'], l2 = ['a', 'b'], How do I generate a statement like this, "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE col_name IN ['a'];" , I've tried the answer and it doesn't work

Comment: l = [1,5,8]  l_str = str(l).replace( '[', '(' ).replace( ']', ')' )

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Answers so far have been templating the values into a plain SQL string. That's absolutely fine for integers, but if we wanted to do it for strings we get the escaping issue.

Here's a variant using a parameterised query that would work for both:

```python
placeholder= '?' # For SQLite. See DBAPI paramstyle.
placeholders= ', '.join(placeholder for unused in l)
query= 'SELECT name FROM students WHERE id IN (%s)' % placeholders
cursor.execute(query, l)
```

Comment: `','.join(placeholder * len(l))` would be a bit shorter while still readable imho

Comment: @Thiefmaster: yes, would have to be `([placeholder]*len(l))` in the general case as the placeholder may be multiple characters.

Comment: @bobince in my case I have assigned a variable a='john' and b='snow' and stored it in a tuple with the name got=['a,b'] and did performed the same query.
Doing this I got the erroy i.e. Type Error: not all arguments converted during string formatting. 
How am I supposed to solbe it

Comment: Why do you want to join "by hand" rather than leave this work to the dbapi? the key is to use a tuple rather than a list...

Comment: @AlessandroDentella, sqlite doesn't support it. The [example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) explicitly adds the `?` in the INSERT clause, which is similar to the IN clause.

Comment: Yeah, passing a tuple as a parameter is something that isn't a standard DB-API feature, and for `%`-paramstyle this probably isn't doing what you think—it's actually calling `str` on the tuple and inserting the Python repr into the query string. That works when it's a tuple of at least two integers, all of which must be too small to get a `L` suffix. It fails for most other cases—and in particular fails for string literals in a way that makes it a SQL injection vulnerability. Don't do that!

Comment: I have a list of repetitive data that shall be passed as placeholders list but sql only executes as set

Comment: Based on this answerm here is a single line solution for ***Python 3.6*** `cursor.execute(f'SELECT name FROM students WHERE id IN ({','.join('?' for _ in l)})', l)`. @bobince, you should also remark in your solution that using `?` is the safe way to go in terms of avoid SQL injection. There are a lot of answers here that are vulnerable, basically any that concatenates strings in python.

Comment: @roganjosh, agreed, and actually wrong: `cursor.execute(f"SELECT name FROM students WHERE id IN ({','.join('?' for _ in l)})", l)`. Unfortunately, there are not a lot of options if you want to avoid SQL injection, I would split the single line into multiple 2 or 3. In this case, a single line is convenient as an example of how to use Python `f-strings`. In the original answer, the 3rd line would look like this: `query= f'SELECT name FROM students WHERE id IN ({placeholders})'`.

Comment: @bobince Is it possible to elaborate more about the comment "all of which must be too small to get a L suffix. It fails for most other cases—and in particular fails for string literals in a way that makes it a SQL injection vulnerability"?

Comment: @LeiHao In Python 2, a number with an L suffix, like `98L` is a long integer. If a number is too large to be a short integer, like `80000000000`, then `repr()` returns the value with an L suffux. Python 3 never does this because the integer type completely handles it Python 3.

Comment: what if I have to pass some extra parameter along with list `l` in the query. `query= 'SELECT name FROM students WHERE id IN (%s) and name= %(name)s' % placeholders` ??

Comment: Reading these comments and the other answers, I see why there have been so many SQL injection vulnerabilities.  Almost no one seems to care (until they're pwned).

Comment: For MySQL use %s instead of ? (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html).

Comment: @toto_tico Thank you very much for your comment, I don't see any instructions on https://linuxhint.com/cursor-execute-python/ to use the question mark as a placeholder, is this unique to cursor or common to python? Where is the description for this?

Comment: @DavidWei, i am not an expert but this is resolved somewhere close to the database, otherwise it wouldn't avoid SQL injections. Basically, when the query is parsed and a ? is encountered, then the first value of the list is used (notice that it is not the sames as simply replacing the value because the DB parser is interpreting the ? in the right context). The documentation will depend on the library/database, e.g., https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-placeholders or https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursorprepared.html

Comment: I encountered a bug when using it, the code is as follows:
placeholder='?'
region_id = '930'
msisdn = ['188']
in_cond = ','.join('?' for _ in msisdn)
query= f"DELETE FROM cloud_financial.tb_ads_timely_user_today_4h_{region_id} WHERE msisdn IN ({in_cond})"
print (query)
'''
DELETE FROM cloud_financial.tb_ads_timely_user_today_4h_930 WHERE msisdn IN (?)
'''
engine_vertica. execute(query, msisdn)
'''
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
'''

Comment: @sigdelsanjog Has this problem been solved? I also encountered, but did not find a solution.

Comment: @DavidWei You should have done `execute(query, (msisdn,)) ` -> the values must be inside a sequence container like a list or tuple, otherwise the single value will be expanded (if it is iterable).

Answer (score 137):

Easiest way is to turn the list to `tuple` first

```
t = tuple(l)
query = "select name from studens where id IN {}".format(t)
```

Comment: As stated by @renstrm, this doesn't work if l just contains one element, you'll end up with id IN (1,). Which is a syntax error.

Comment: if you have only one element, then you don't need to use `IN`. you can simply do `=`

Comment: @Amirhos Imani and what if you don't know how many elements you have?

Comment: @Boris if you can't guarantee that your input is always a list, you can do something similar to this one liner https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38821586/one-line-to-check-if-string-or-list-then-convert-to-list-in-python before passing the argument to your query

Comment: This, like most answers here other than the accepted one, is vulnerable to SQL injection and should not be used.

Comment: @BaconBits Fair warning, but for some applications where SQL injection is not an issue (for example, analysis of a database where I am the only user), this will do.

Comment: yeah this doesnt work for one element, just realized

Comment: In case of single value check length of list should be one then convert it to like this `'({0})'.format(str(list[0]))`

Comment: yeah, incase of single value it adds empty one, so i used this. 
`query = "DELETE FROM some_table WHERE id IN {ids}".format( ids='(' + str(your_arr[0]) + ')' if len(your_arr) == 1 else tuple(your_arr))`

Answer (score 37):

Dont complicate it, Solution for this is simple.

```
l = [1,5,8]

l = tuple(l)

params = {'l': l}

cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table where id in %(l)s',params)
```

[image]

I hope this helped !!!

Comment: This doesn't work if `l` just contains one element, you'll end up with `id IN (1,)`. Which is a syntax error.

Comment: If it is only one element , IN is not the operator you are looking for.OP clearly doesn;t.

Comment: If l only contains 1 element be sure it's a tuple and it WILL work. This solution is clearer in my opinion than the accepted one.

Comment: But it still won't work if tuple is empty, so there must be additional check before query execution.

Comment: Some database connectors (like pyodbc connecting to SQL Server) don't support named parameters, so this won't always work.

Comment: This doesn't work for me with `sqlite3`. What library did you test this against?

Comment: This is the best example as it has a simple string creation solution and also prevents sql injection.

Comment: Good solution but @renstrm and Никита-Конин are right about requiring additional checks for when the tuple has a single element or no elements.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I use redshift and pandas, there it's:
`pd.read_sql_query(sql='select * from table where id in :ids_tuple', con=..., params={'ids_tuple':l});`
Very convenient. and you can substitute the lists of ids in a cycle without  recompilation of the query.

Answer (score 32):

The SQL you want is

```
select name from studens where id in (1, 5, 8)
```

If you want to construct this from the python you could use

```
l = [1, 5, 8]
sql_query = 'select name from studens where id in (' + ','.join(map(str, l)) + ')'
```

The [map](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) function will transform the list into a list of strings that can be glued together by commas using the [str.join](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method.

Alternatively:

```
l = [1, 5, 8]
sql_query = 'select name from studens where id in (' + ','.join((str(n) for n in l)) + ')'
```

if you prefer [generator expressions](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-generator-expression) to the map function.

UPDATE: [S. Lott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10661/slott) mentions in the comments that the Python SQLite bindings don't support sequences. In that case, you might want

```
select name from studens where id = 1 or id = 5 or id = 8
```

Generated by

```
sql_query = 'select name from studens where ' + ' or '.join(('id = ' + str(n) for n in l))
```

Comment: :-( Python SQLite binding doesn't support sequences.

Comment: Oh? I didn't realize. Then again, I didn't realize we were going for a SQLite binding solution.

Comment: Sorry, not suggesting or implying SQLite -- just sad that bindings for lists don't work there.

Answer (score 10):

[string.join](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the list values separated by commas, and use the [format operator](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) to form a query string.

```
myquery = "select name from studens where id in (%s)" % ",".join(map(str,mylist))
```

(Thanks, [blair-conrad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1199/blair-conrad))

Comment: Since this approach doesn't use database parameter substitution, it exposes you to SQL injection attacks. The `%` being used here is just plain Python string formatting.

Answer (score 10):

I like bobince's answer:

```
placeholder= '?' # For SQLite. See DBAPI paramstyle.
placeholders= ', '.join(placeholder for unused in l)
query= 'SELECT name FROM students WHERE id IN (%s)' % placeholders
cursor.execute(query, l)
```

But I noticed this:

```
placeholders= ', '.join(placeholder for unused in l)
```

Can be replaced with:

```
placeholders= ', '.join(placeholder*len(l))
```

I find this more direct if less clever and less general. Here `l` is required to have a length (i.e. refer to an object that defines a `__len__` method), which shouldn't be a problem. But placeholder must also be a single character. To support a multi-character placeholder use:

```
placeholders= ', '.join([placeholder]*len(l))
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're using PostgreSQL with the Psycopg2 library you can let its [tuple adaption](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#tuples-adaptation) do all the escaping and string interpolation for you, e.g:

```
ids = [1,2,3]
cur.execute(
  "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id IN %s",
  [tuple(ids)])
```

i.e. just make sure that you're passing the `IN` parameter as a `tuple`.  if it's a `list` you can use the [`= ANY` array syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.28.16):

```
cur.execute(
  "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id = ANY (%s)",
  [list(ids)])
```

note that these both will get turned into the same query plan so you should just use whichever is easier. e.g. if your list comes in a tuple use the former, if they're stored in a list use the latter.

Answer (score 5):

Just use inline if operation with tuple function:

```
query = "Select * from hr_employee WHERE id in " % tuple(employee_ids) if len(employee_ids) != 1 else "("+ str(employee_ids[0]) + ")"
```

Comment: My problem was with parameterised queries. The injected list param, always ended up having its values surrounded by quotes in the resulting SQL `IN` clauses which was confusing as hell. The `tuple()` idea worked. It works because DJango translates that into a string format suited to an SQL `IN()` clause. It was this that didn't click for me when several answers suggested using the `tuple`.

Answer (score 4):

Solution for @umounted answer, because that broke with a one-element tuple, since (1,) is not valid SQL.:

```
>>> random_ids = [1234,123,54,56,57,58,78,91]
>>> cursor.execute("create table test (id)")
>>> for item in random_ids:
    cursor.execute("insert into test values (%d)" % item)
>>> sublist = [56,57,58]
>>> cursor.execute("select id from test where id in %s" % str(tuple(sublist)).replace(',)',')'))
>>> a = cursor.fetchall()
>>> a
[(56,), (57,), (58,)]
```

Other solution for sql string:

```
cursor.execute("select id from test where id in (%s)" % ('"'+'", "'.join(l)+'"'))
```

Comment: This is not better solution because of sql injection.

Answer (score 4):

```
l = [1] # or [1,2,3]

query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN :l"
params = {'l' : tuple(l)}
cursor.execute(query, params)
```

The `:var` notation seems simpler. (Python 3.7)

Answer (score 4):

To run a select from where field is in list of strings (instead of int), [as per this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741185/add-quotes-to-every-list-element) use `repr(tuple(map(str, l)))`. Full example:

```
l = ['a','b','c']
sql = f'''

select name 
from students 
where id in {repr(tuple(map(str, l)))}
'''
print(sql)
```

Returns:
 `select name  from students  where id in ('a', 'b', 'c')`

For a list of dates in Oracle, this worked

```
l = ['2020-11-24', '2020-12-28']
dates_str = ','.join([f'DATE {repr(s)}' for s in l])
dates_str = f'({dates_str})'

sql_cmd = f'''
select *
from students 
where 
and date in {dates_str}
'''
```

Returns:
`select * from students  where  and date in (DATE '2020-11-24',DATE '2020-12-28')`

If you need to get the list of dates from a pandas df, it's `df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').unique()`

And since I often needed it too, adding columns from a list

```
# single list
f'select {','.join(l)}'

# multi list in different tables
sql_cmd = f'''
select {','.join(f't1.{s}' for s in l1)},
{','.join(f't1.{s}' for s in l2)},
{','.join(f't2.{s}' for s in l3)}  
'''
```

Comment: it solved my problem in python2.7..Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

```
placeholders= ', '.join("'{"+str(i)+"}'" for i in range(len(l)))
query="select name from students where id (%s)"%placeholders
query=query.format(*l)
cursor.execute(query)
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

a simpler solution - convert list to string, remove square brackets and add round brackets:

```
lst = [1,2,3,a,b,c]

query = f"""SELECT * FROM table WHERE IN ({str(lst)[1:-1]})"""
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, if you want the sql query:

```
select name from studens where id in (1, 5, 8)
```

What about:

```
my_list = [1, 5, 8]
cur.execute("select name from studens where id in %s" % repr(my_list).replace('[','(').replace(']',')') )
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses parameter substitution and takes care of the single value list case:

```
l = [1,5,8]

get_operator = lambda x: '=' if len(x) == 1 else 'IN'
get_value = lambda x: int(x[0]) if len(x) == 1 else x

query = 'SELECT * FROM table where id ' + get_operator(l) + ' %s'

cursor.execute(query, (get_value(l),))
```

Answer (score 0):

This Will Work If Number of  Values in List equals to 1 or greater than 1

```
t = str(tuple(l))
if t[-2] == ',':
   t= t.replace(t[-2],"")
query = "select name from studens where id IN {}".format(t)
```