# Does the MySQLdb module support prepared statements?

Tags: python, mysql, prepared-statement

Does MySQLdb support server-side [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)? I can't figure this out from its manual.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check the MySQLdb [Package Comments](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/):

> "Parameterization" is done in MySQLdb by escaping strings and then blindly interpolating them into the query, instead of using the MYSQL_STMT API. As a result unicode strings have to go through two intermediate representations (encoded string, escaped encoded string) before they're received by the database.

So the answer is: No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 12):

It has some kind of parameterization, [yes](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples).

Even then, I advise you switch to [oursql](https://launchpad.net/oursql). It brings [a lot of advantages](http://packages.python.org/oursql/) over MySQLdb:

- oursql has real parameterization.
- oursql allows text or binary data to be streamed into the database and streamed out of the database, instead of requiring everything to be buffered in the client.
- oursql can both insert rows lazily and fetch rows lazily.
- oursql has unicode support on by default.
- oursql supports python 2.4 through 2.7 without any deprecation warnings on 2.6+ (see PEP 218) and without completely failing on 2.7 (see PEP 328).
- oursql is licensed under the BSD license.

Comment: oursql is a dead project - https://launchpad.net/oursql redirects to https://github.com/python-oursql/oursql with last commit in 2016