# Python & MySql: Unicode and Encoding

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, utf-8, encode

I am parsing json data and trying to store some of the json data into Mysql database. I am currently getting following unicode error. My question is how should I handle this.

- Should I handle it from the database side, and if so how can I modify my table to do so?
- Should I handle it from python side?

Here is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE yahoo_questions (
   question_id varchar(40) NOT NULL, 
   question_subj varbinary(255), 
   question_content varbinary(255),
   question_userId varchar(40) NOT NULL,
   question_timestamp varchar(40),
   category_id varbinary(20) NOT NULL,
   category_name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
   choosen_answer varbinary(255),
   choosen_userId varchar(40),
   choosen_usernick varchar(40),
   choosen_ans_timestamp varchar(40),
   UNIQUE (question_id)
);
```

Error While inserting via python code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "YahooQueryData.py", line 78, in <module>
    +"VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (row[2], row[5], row[6], quserId, questionTime, categoryId, categoryName, qChosenAnswer, choosenUserId, choosenNickName, choosenTimeStamp))
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 159, in execute
    query = query % db.literal(args)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 264, in literal
    return self.escape(o, self.encoders)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 202, in unicode_literal
    return db.literal(u.encode(unicode_literal.charset))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 204-230: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Python Code segment:

```
    #pushing user id to the url to get full json stack
    urlobject = urllib.urlopen(base_url.format(row[2]))
    qnadatajson = urlobject.read()
    data = json.loads(qnadatajson)
cur.execute("INSERT INTO yahoo_questions (question_id, question_subj, question_content, question_userId, question_timestamp,"
            +"category_id, category_name, choosen_answer, choosen_userId, choosen_usernick, choosen_ans_timestamp)"
            +"VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (row[2], row[5], row[6], quserId, questionTime, categoryId, categoryName, qChosenAnswer, choosenUserId, choosenNickName, choosenTimeStamp))
```

json Structure

```
questions: [
{
Id: "20111201185322AA5HTDc",
Subject: "what are the new pokemon call?",
Content: "I used to know them I stop at dialga and palkia version and I heard there's new ones what's it call
",
Date: "2011-12-01 18:53:22",
Timestamp: "1322794402",
```

What I also did prior to running the query I execute the following on `mysql SET character_set_client = utf8`

And this how the mysql variables looks like:

```
mysql> SHOW variables LIKE '%character_set%';
+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                                  |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                                   |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                                   |
| character_set_database   | latin1                                                 |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                                 |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                                   |
| character_set_server     | latin1                                                 |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                                   |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/local/mysql-5.5.10-osx10.6-x86_64/share/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: The usual "get mysql to accept utf8" incantation is to make sure that `SET NAMES 'utf8'` is your very first query when opening the connection. Have you tried that instead of `character_set_client`? (This is just a comment because I don't think that's the problem here, based on your var output. I think your MYSQLdb Python library is trying to encode to latin-1 and doesn't know it should be encoding to utf-8. Check the documentation and see if there is some way to inform it of this fact.)

Comment: Your problem is with the %s, you're trying to convert unicode data into a string. I have the same problem, just not sure how to fix it...

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I think that your MYSQLdb python library doesn't know it's supposed to encode to utf8, and is encoding to the default python system-defined charset `latin1`.

When you `connect()` to your database, pass the `charset='utf8'` parameter.  This should also make a manual `SET NAMES` or `SET character_set_client` unnecessary.

Comment: con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'XXXX', 
        'XXXX', 'XXXX', unix_socket='/tmp/mysql.sock', charset='utf8') is this what you meant...?

Comment: That is what I meant. However, I'm now not sure from the documentation if you need to `SET NAMES utf8` also or not. I would try both.

Comment: Now i am having strange json error after 300 some records.. strange but this was a great help.

Comment: Which one? `charset` by itself, or did you need `SET NAMES` too? Let me know so I can update the answer. (And accept/check the answer if it worked.)

Comment: what I have is exactly what I put in the first comment: charset='utf8', so charset worked.

Comment: But did you remove your `SET NAMES utf8` and/or `SET character_set_client=utf8` query as well, or not?

Comment: good question no I didn't remove SET character_set_client=utf8 I didn't do SET NAMES  utf8

Comment: After 4 hours of debugging/googling, you saved me! in my case, I was missing `charset='utf8mb4'` when connecting to db.

Comment: mysql_connection = MySQLdb.connect(host, username, password, mysql_database_name, port, charset='utf8')                                                     
                                                                                                                         
  thank you @FrancisAvila.  this solved my problem!!

Answer (score 42):

First, make sure you are assigning the **`charset`** and **`use_unicode`** parameters when making your MySQL connection:

```
conn = mysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
                     user='user',
                     passwd='passwd',
                     db='db',
                     charset='utf8',
                     use_unicode=True)
```

Secondly, use [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947750/does-python-support-mysql-prepared-statements) when actually querying the database. Below is an example INSERT query of a string containing a unicode character.

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (null, %s)',                  
               ('Some string that contains unicode: ' + unichr(300),))
```

Comment: None of the other answers mention the prepared statement issue; that was the trick for me.  Related: to escape the percent sign in a python format string with %s, etc, like for queries with LIKE, or date formats, use a double-percent sign %%

Answer (score 1):

Still facing the same issue, 
try to downgraded your mysql-connector-python version, this is work for me.

Change **mysql-connector-python==8.0.30** to **mysql-connector-python==8.0.28**.

Copy this,

```
pip uninstall mysql-connector-python==8.0.30

pip install mysql-connector-python==8.0.28
```