# How to encode (utf8mb4) in Python

Tags: python, mysql, encoding, utf-8

How do I encode something in ut8mb4 in Python?

I have two sets of data: data I am migrating to my new MySQL database over from Parse, and data going forward (that talks only to my new database). My database is utf8mb4 in order to store emoji and accented letters.

The first set of data only shows up correctly (when emoji and accents are involved) when I have in my python script:

```
MySQLdb.escape_string(unicode(xstr(data.get('message'))).encode('utf-8'))
```

and when reading from the MySQL database in PHP:

```
$row["message"] = utf8_encode($row["message"]);
```

The second set of data only shows up correctly (when emoji and accents are involved) when I DON'T include the `utf8_encode($row["message"])` portion. I am trying to reconcile these so that both sets of data are returned correctly to my iOS app. Please help!

Comment: I presume you're talking about MySQL? If so then Python's utf8 should be identical to MySQL's utf8mb4. Can you be more specific about what you're doing and the results you see?

Comment: It seems utf8mb4 is something MySQL invented because their ut8 implementation only works with BMP characters. This is not the case for normal utf8, which can encode any unicode character. That's the encoding that Python is using. Perhaps MySQL provides a set of functions for working with their custom encoding?

Comment: @MarkRansom have added more to the question to be more specific

Comment: It is not clear as to a) what your data looks like in both cases and b) what the data looks like when it doesn't work. Please define clearly what problems you are seeing.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

MySQL's [`utf8mb4` encoding](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html) is **just standard UTF-8**.

They had to add that name however to distinguish it from the [*broken* UTF-8 character set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html) which only supported BMP characters.

In other words, from the Python side you should always encode to UTF-8 when talking to MySQL, but take into account that the database may not be able to handle Unicode codepoints beyond U+FFFF, unless you use `utf8mb4` *on the MySQL side*.

However, generally speaking, you want to avoid *manually* encoding and decoding, and instead leave it to `MySQLdb` worry about this. You do this by configuring your connection and your collations to handle Unicode text transparently. For `MySQLdb`, that means setting `charset='utf8mb4'`:

```
database = MySQLdb.connect(
    host=hostname,
    user=username,
    passwd=password,
    db=databasename,
    charset="utf8mb4"
)
```

Then use normal Python 3 `str` strings; leave the `use_unicode` option set to it's default `True`<sup>*</sup>.

Note: this [handles `SET NAMES` and `SET character_set_connection`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365660/python-mysql-unicode-and-encoding)) *for you*, there is no need to issue those manually.

---

<sup>*</sup> Unless you still use Python 2, then the default is `False`. Set it to `True` and use `u'...'` unicode strings.

Answer (score 28):

I have struggled myself with the correct exchange of the full range of UTF-8 characters between Python and MySQL for the sake of Emoji and other characters beyond the U+FFFF codepoint.

To be sure that everything worked fine, I had to do the following:

1. make sure `utf8mb4` was used for `CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, and `TEXT` columns in MySQL
2. enforce UTF-8 in Python
3. enforce UTF-8 to be used between Python and MySQL

To enforce UTF-8 in Python, add the following line as first or second line of your Python script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

To enforce UTF-8 between Python and MySQL, setup the MySQL connection as follows:

```
# Connect to mysql.
dbc = MySQLdb.connect(host='###', user='###', passwd='###', db='###', use_unicode=True)

# Create a cursor.
cursor = dbc.cursor()

# Enforce UTF-8 for the connection.
cursor.execute('SET NAMES utf8mb4')
cursor.execute("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4")
cursor.execute("SET character_set_connection=utf8mb4")

# Do database stuff.

# Commit data.
dbc.commit()

# Close cursor and connection.
cursor.close()
dbc.close()
```

This way, you don't need to use functions such as `encode` and `utf8_encode`.

Comment: Very useful checklist. Rescued me from a steaming .

Comment: This fixes the issue I was experiencing with mysql + python + emojis 

Comment: The `coding` line applies *only to how Python decodes string literals in source code*. Not to how encoding and decoding of *data* is handled. Unless this is Python 2 and you used non-ASCII characters in string literals, there is no need to set this. In Python 3, UTF-8 is *the default source encoding*.

Comment: Beware of this answer if you are on Python3! I've a MySQL database using utf8mb collation. I use MySQLdb with Python3 and I do not need to do anything special to properly read unicode characters. I tried your suggestion and it turned out to perform some sort of double encoding on data, returning some weird unicode characters instead of the right ones.

Comment: @baxeico I am not sure if I ever tested my answer in Python 3 back in the day. I know that above was a big issue in Python 2. I'll do some testing in Python 3 and update my answer.

Comment: Actually all I need to add is charset='utf8' argument to mysqldb.connect call.

Comment: I already had the charset='utf8' argument in my connect call but it only worked for me when I added the three `cursor.execute` commands. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`use_unicode=True` didn't work for me.

My solution

- in mysql, change entire database, table and field encoding to utf8mb4
- `MySQLdb.connect(host='###' [...], charset='utf8'`
- `dbCursor.execute('SET NAMES utf8mb4')`
- `dbCursor.execute("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4")`

Answer (score 2):

You can also enter the type of code that you want in the following way

```py
mysql.connector.connect(host = '<host>', database = '<db>', user = '<user>', password = '<password>', charset = 'utf8')
```

The fields inside '<>' are your own details. Instead of 'utf8' you can also write 'utf8mb4' depending on the type of coding your mysqldb wants.