# In Python, how to replace all non-UTF-8 characters in a string?

Tags: python, mysql, encoding, utf-8

**Update: The real problem is that MySQL utf8 does not support four-byte UTF-8 characters.**

There are several questions on this topic, but none of them seems to be my question exactly, except for maybe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26541968/delete-every-non-utf-8-symbols-froms-string), where the accepted answer does not work for me.

I am coding in Python with the `MySQLdb` module, and I want to put some text into a MySQL database.  The database is configured for UTF-8, but the text occasionally contains <del>non-UTF-8</del> four-byte-UTF-8 characters.

The Python code for the database modification looks like this:

```
connection = MySQLdb.connect(
    'localhost',
    'root',
    '',
    'mydatabase',
    charset='utf8',
    use_unicode=True)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(
    'update mytable set entryContent=%s where entryName=%s',
    (entryContent, entryName))
connection.commit()
```

And it currently produces this warning:

```
./myapp.py:233: Warning: Invalid utf8 character string: 'F09286'
  (entry, word))
./myapp.py:233: Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x92\x86\xB7\xF0\x92...' for column 'entry' at row 1
  (entryname, entrycontent))
```

When I look at what actually got into the database with the `mysql` command-line client, I see the content truncated at the very first occurrence of a <del>non-UTF-8</del> four-byte UTF-8 character.

I don't care about preserving the <del>non-UTF-8</del> four-byte UTF-8 characters, so all I want to do is replace all <del>non-UTF-8</del> four-byte UTF-8 characters with some other valid UTF-8 character, so I can put the text into the database.

Comment: `entry.decode().encode('ascii', 'replace')`

Comment: @Peter Wood: `'Cognates include Hittite  ‎(lāman)'.decode().encode('ascii', 'replace')` produces `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 25: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: Sorry, `'Cognates include Hittite  ‎(lāman)'.decode('utf-8').encode('ascii', 'replace')`, gives `'Cognates include Hittite ???????? ?(l?man)'`

Answer (score 4):

You will need to set your table encoding to `utf8mb4` to support 4 byte UTF-8 encoding - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html

Also, the MySQL driver supports Unicode strings, so you should pass Unicode to free your code from encoding specifics:

E.g.

```
cursor.execute(u'update mytable set entryContent=%s where entryName=%s',
(entryContent.decode("utf-8"), entryName.decode("utf-8")))
```

Ideally, `entryContent` and `entryName` will have been decoded to Unicode earlier in your code when you first receive them. E.g. when opening a file or receiving from the network.

Comment: It chokes on four-byte UTF-8 characters.  Three-byte (and fewer) UTF-8 characters are fine.

Comment: Even when you pass Unicode (opposed to the str shown in your question)?

Comment: Have you set your table to `utf8mb4` encoding? See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html

Comment: No!  That may be the true best answer!

Comment: Success! This answer was extremely helpful, but there was a little more work required.  After reconfiguring the database, table, and column to use `utf8mb4` (instead of just `utf8`) with [this](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4), I discovered that MySQLdb.connect() raised a `LookupError` when I requested a connection with `charset=utf8mb4`, but I could change this post-connection by configuring the cursor as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27390024/1555925).

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the problem is **not** that I am feeding **non-UTF-8** characters to MySQL, but that I am feeding **four-byte UTF-8** characters to MySQL when it supports only three-(and fewer)byte UTF-8 characters ([according to this documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html))

This solution retains all the supported UTF-8 characters, and converts the unsupported UTF-8 characters to '?':

```
>>> print ''.join([c if len(c.encode('utf-8')) < 4 else '?' for c in u'Cognates include Hittite  ‎(lāman)'])
Cognates include Hittite ???? ‎(lāman)
```

- Notice that 'ā' is retained
- Notice that '' has become '????'

I can put this string into MySQL without the above warnings (and undesirable truncation).

Comment: Yes, the real problem was that I did not know of `utf8mb4`.

Answer (score 2):

Could you use a regular expression to remove non-ascii characters? Using your example in the comments:

```
>>> entry = 'Cognates include Hittite  ‎(lāman)'
>>> entry = ''.join([char if ord(char) < 128 else '' for char in entry])
>>> print entry
Cognates include Hittite  (lman)
```

This is a slight variation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26541968/delete-every-non-utf-8-symbols-froms-string) to a different problem.

Comment: I want to keep (three-byte) UTF-8 characters, but this answer removes many UTF-8 characters.