# how do I insert some rows that I select from remote MySQL database to my local MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pymysql

My remote MySQL database and local MySQL database have the same table structure, and the remote and local MySQL database is `utf-8`charset.

Comment: What did you get if you insert those to mysql, and what displays in your table if you insert successfully.

Comment: @kcorlidy Hi, I edited my question, the sql is so simple, and my problem is not about the sql sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better merge value and sql template string and print it , make sure the sql is correct.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question, the sql is so simple, and my problem is not about the sql sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I know you are using python-2.x, but i am not sure what kinds of module you are importing. So i write so.

> You only need to set charset="utf8" than you can write data successfully.

```
try:
    import mysql.connector as mysql
except Exception as e:
    import MySQLdb as mysql

connection = mysql.connect(user="k",passwd="k",db="k",charset="utf8")
mycursor = connection.cursor()
data = (222, u'yy', u'm', u'\u60a8\u597d'.encode("utf8"))
# data = (222, u'yy', u'm', u'\u60a8\u597d') #python-3.x
data = "insert into students (id_card, name, sex, order_info) values({}, '{}', '{}', '{}')".format(*data)
mycursor.execute(data)
connection.commit()
```

Reference
  [Python & MySql: Unicode and Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365660/python-mysql-unicode-and-encoding)