# Like statement in DataBase with Python

Tags: python, mysql, database

I'm still learning Python as great simple programming language, the problem came with DataBase , I'm using MySQL to build it then I want to Select some tuples from Python code as I did write the query as following:

```
Q = "INSERT INTO contacts (FirstName,LastName,phone,mobile,email,address) VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s') "% \
            (FN,LN,phone,Mobile,email,address)
```

becuase of using variables and it's OK.
but If I want to use (LIKE'') statement in query I get into quotations troubles ! as following:

```
    Q = "SELECT LastName FROM contacts WHERE phone LIKE '_'%s'%'" %\
            (phone)
```

What can I do to solve this problem, any hints ?

Comment: Python has serval impressive ORMs one of these is [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) maybe you should take a look at it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947750/does-python-support-mysql-prepared-statements) and avoid the troubles of string formatting:

```
pattern = "_" + phone + "%"
cursor.execute("SELECT LastName FROM contacts WHERE phone LIKE %s", (pattern,))
```

If you don't want to use prepared statements, or if you stumble upon this problem in other cases, switch to using [str.format](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) (but read about [SQL injections](http://bobby-tables.com/) before doing this):

```
Q = "SELECT LastName FROM contacts WHERE phone LIKE '_{0}%'".format(phone)
```

Or combine the two:

```
pattern = "_{0}%".format(phone)
cursor.execute("SELECT LastName FROM contacts WHERE phone LIKE %s", (pattern,))
```

Comment: Please also add an example of a prepared statement, beginners will take your example 1:1 which is a real risk!

Comment: dav1d, you are of course correct. I've added it and restructured my answer to use prepared statements first.

Comment: That is not a prepared statement what you use. These always use `?` notation. Using the `%s` notation, MySQLdb internally assembles the queries in a safe way (`mysql_real_string_escape()`), but doesn't use prep statements.

Comment: glglgl, that's interesting, I didn't know that. I thought prepared statements was the only way to parameterize a query.