# Using a lot of %s in program, how to put variables at the end in multiline?

Tags: python

For example:

```
command """%s abc %s,
        abs %s jfh %s etc...""" % (var1, var2, var3, var4)
```

I need to write that vars in multiline because there are a lot of them in code (for updating database).

Tested:

```
% (var1, var2,\
var3,var4)
```

not working. (Also tested without "," at the end of first line)

Error: Showing last ")" and:

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

PS. We got a good answer to this question, also problem was "%s"""" at the end, it should be: "%s" """ - yes, one blank space solves problem)))

Comment: "I need to write that vars in multiline because there are a lot of them in code (for updating database)." **WARNING** - do __not__ build queries using string concatenation or formatting, instead use __prepared statements__. Building queries using string concatenation or string templating makes you susceptible to SQL injection when accepting user input.

Comment: In continuation to @Benjamin Gruenbaum comment one more thing is that table names cannot be parameterized in SQL, that can cause a very annoying error.

Comment: What do you mean not working? Errors (provide traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs, expected outputs, actual outputs)? You have a missing `=`, could that be it? Also, parentheses give implicit line continuation in Python, you don't need \.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947750/does-python-support-mysql-prepared-statements

Comment: @EminMastizada that's through `cursor.execute` - note that even if _you_ are not doing anything wrong in your SQL queries - a lot of people read questions on this site and I want _them_ to be aware to the issues this might cause too.

Comment: just remove "\" and have try, I think it should work.

Comment: @user3239580 already tested: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: It appears your string literal is broken. Do you have the right number and type of quotation marks on each side? Are you sure you didn't accidentally put in curly quotes?

Comment: @EminMastizada but at least MySQLdb escapes the input for you.

Comment: @rmartinjak its just getting some variables for me and saves in my database for feature usage. Before sending I'm deleting most symbols from variables. Also strings like "" is not be problem for mysql

Comment: There's also http://pythonhosted.org/oursql/ which provides real parametrization.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ignoring the valid SQL concerns, a better way to handle a multiline string problem is with [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). This way you can store all your "data" in a dictionary and format at the very end. This will avoid `(var1, var2, ..., varN)`. For example:

```
data = {'name':'Hooked',
        'site':'Stack Overflow',
        'adj' :'awesome'}

s = "{name} thinks {site} is {adj}!"

print s.format(**data)

#>> Hooked thinks Stack Overflow is awesome!
```