# How to store text file into MySQL database using python

Tags: python-2.7

```
import MySQLdb
import re

def write():
    file = open('/home/fixstream/Desktop/test10.txt', 'r')
    print file.read()
    file.close()
write()
```

Above code i have, now i want to store the text file into mysql db. I am new to python as well as database. So anyone can help me with this?

Comment: You've written barely enough code to open the file. But there's is no code to parse it, or to connect to the database. Look up a few examples and come back with an example of an objective problem you are having.

Answer (score 11):

I suggest you reading [this MySQLdb tutorial](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlpython/).
First, you need to store content of the file in a variable. Then it's simply connecting to your database (which is done as you can see in the link) and then executing INSERT query. Prepared statements are [done in similar way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947750/does-python-support-mysql-prepared-statements/1947993#1947993) as common string formatting in python.

You need something like this:

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","user","password","database")
cursor = db.cursor()

file = open('/home/fixstream/Desktop/test10.txt', 'r')
file_content = file.read()
file.close()

query = "INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s)"

cursor.execute(query, (file_content,))

db.commit()
db.close()
```

Note the comma after file_content - this ensures the second argument for execute() is a tuple. Also note db.commit() which ensures writing changes.

If you need further explanation, ask.