# Store unknown text file data into MySQL using Python

Tags: python, mysql

To go more in depth into a question like this:

[How to store text file into MySQL database using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25258905/how-to-store-text-file-into-mysql-database-using-python)

I have data that I am uncertain what it will be until my Python script reads the file. So the error I am getting is:

`MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: not enough arguments for format string`

Here's my code:

`file = open('./ftp_files/ReadMe.txt', 'r')`
  `file_content = file.read()`
  `for line in file_content:`
    `fields = line.split('|')`
  `file.close()`

`query = "INSERT INTO ICLN_LOADER_JOB_LOG (JOB_ID, LOADER_HOST_NAME, MYSQL_HOST_NAME) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')"`

`cursor.execute(query, (file_content,))`

I understand that normally you would have the data values after `%s`... but what if I don't know what those values are, how can I set it up so that Python reads what the file content is and fills in the gaps?

Answer (score 0):

That depends how you defined the table ICLN_LOADER_JOB_LOG

IF LOADER_HOST_NAME and  MYSQL_HOST_NAME alloow NULL as Value. you can do this

```
query = """INSERT INTO ICLN_LOADER_JOB_LOG (JOB_ID, LOADER_HOST_NAME, MYSQL_HOST_NAME) 
         VALUES ('%s', NULL, NULL)"""

cursor.execute(query, (file_content,))
```

Also you could use instead of NULL other values that mark , the columns had no value

Like

```
query = """INSERT INTO ICLN_LOADER_JOB_LOG (JOB_ID, LOADER_HOST_NAME, MYSQL_HOST_NAME) 
         VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')"""
lhn = '';
myhn = '';
cursor.execute(query, (file_content,lhn,mysn))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert any values into a string using .format() method. But your problem should be that you are closing your file before you use file_content.