# Python - MySQLdb - data not inserted into table

Tags: python, mysql, sql-insert, mysql-python

I am trying to enter data into MySQL table using MySQLdb but it is not inserting data into table.
my code is :

```
      try:
            db = MySQLdb.Connect("127.0.0.1","root","root","bank")
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT max(account_number) from pybank")
            results = cursor.fetchall()
            for row in results:
                self.account_number = row[0]
            sql = "INSERT INTO pybank(account_number,user_name, user_age, user_dob, amount) VALUES(%d,'%s',%d,'%s',%d)" %(self.account_number + 1,self.user_name, self.user_age, self.user_dob, self.total_amount)
            print(sql)

            cr = db.cursor()
            cr.execute(sql)
            db.commit()
            print("Your have successfully created your account")
            self.getAccountDetails()
        except:
            db.rollback()
            print("Your account is not created !!!! ")
            print
            print("Please try again")
```

Comment: Remove your try-except block and try it again to get a traceback.

Comment: @wenzul thanks for your help. It solved my problem.

Comment: For the sake of security look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947750/does-python-support-mysql-prepared-statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mistype in SQL near VALUES, also you should use placeholders:

```
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO pybank (account_number,user_name, user_age, user_dob, amount) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (self.account_number + 1, self.user_name, self.user_age, self.user_dob, self.total_amount))
```

Comment: actually problem was with column name. now its working fine.