# Python MySQLdb passing a list into an insert statement

Tags: python, mysql-python

I am trying to pass some values from a list into an insert statement and thought it would be straightforward enough but I find myself wasting far too much time on this:

please could someone explain what's going wrong here?

#### WORKS WITH HARDCODED LIST of values

```
cursor=db.cursor()
cursor.execute(" INSERT INTO a (a,b) VALUES (%s,%s)", ('abc', 'abc'))
db.commit()
cursor.close()
```

#### DOESN'T WORK with list of values as a variable (output_insert)

```
output = ('abc','abc')
output_insert = str(output)
cursor=db.cursor()
sql = '" INSERT INTO a (a,b) VALUES (%s,%s)",' +  output_insert
cursor.execute(sql)
db.commit()
cursor.close()
```

if I print the sencond statement, I can see that it is identical to the first that fails:

print sql

" INSERT INTO a (a,b) VALUES (%s,%s)",('abc', 'abc')

same as:

" INSERT INTO a (a,b) VALUES (%s,%s)", ('abc', 'abc')

The error returned is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'" INSERT INTO a (a,b) VALUES (%s,%s)",(\'abc\', \'abc\')\' at line 1')
```

Thanks!

Comment: could be useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/1947993/20774

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you print the `sql` you give to mysql:

```
" INSERT INTO a (a,b) VALUES (%s,%s)",('abc', 'abc')
```

It's not a right sql for MySQL, so you got error.

Or You can use string format method to format sql, example as:

```
cursor=db.cursor()
vars_sql = ('abc', 'abc')
sql_format = "INSERT INTO a (a,b) VALUES ('{0}','{1}')"
real_sql = sql_format.format(*vars_sql)
# print out see if sql is correct
print real_sql
# not use format string avoid dangerous
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO a (a,b) VALUES ('%s','%s')", ('abc', 'abc'))
db.commit()
cursor.close()
```

in this way, you can print out the real sql and execute in MySQL to see if anything wrong with the sql.

Comment: Don't suggest creating SQL queries using the string format. It is database security 101 - dangerous and error-prompt.

Comment: lol, I don't suggest you assume that I don't know the data I'm dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't use string interpolation or string formatting to create SQL queries.** You are making your code vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks and getting type conversion and quote-handling problems (as you can already see).

Instead, *parameterize your query*. The query parameters should be passed as a separate argument to `execute()`:

```
output = ('abc','abc')
sql = """
    INSERT INTO 
        a 
        (a, b) 
    VALUES 
        (%s, %s)"""
cursor.execute(sql, output)
```

Comment: no, unfortunately not:

output = ('abc','abc')
cursor=db.cursor()
sql = '""" INSERT INTO a (a,b) VALUES (%s,%s)""",'
cursor.execute(sql,output_insert)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 159, in execute
    query = query % db.literal(args)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Comment: @LongDog no, you are not executing exactly what I have posted - the query parameters should be passed as a tuple - see the `output` variable I'm using? *Don't use string formatting to create sql queries.*