# Input variable in SQLquery

Tags: python, sql

Is there someone who knows how I can put an input variable (user input) in a SQLQuery in Python?

```
 x = str(input("some text"))

sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE columname = x "
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: What about concatenate your string and the user input ?

Comment: Learn about prepared statements

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947750/does-python-support-mysql-prepared-statements

Answer (score 0):

you could concatenate the strings, Be aware however, that this leaves you vulnerable for SQL injection.

which would make your example

```
x = str(input("some text"))
sqlQuery = ("SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE columname = " + x)
```

or, a more readable version

```
sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE columname = %s" % (x)
```

Comment: Really? What about SQL injection??

Comment: you should handle that in the input, the question was how to enter a variable in the query, i agree that you should sanetize your inputs, but that wasn't the question

Comment: I agree with @apomene, you should add a warning, since examples tend to get copy&pasted without thinking about (or even knowing) the implications. Also your example _does_ include the user input... ;-)