# Python : huge looping in SQL Table

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

in mySql I have the following table (named "staff" )of 800 records (might be much higher):

```
     day          start_time              end_time     
   -----------------------------------------------------------------     
 2017-01-05 |   2017-01-05 08:00:00    2017-01-05 17:00:00  
 2017-01-06 |   2017-01-06 08:00:00    2017-01-06 17:00:00 
 2017-01-09 |   2017-01-09 08:00:00    2017-01-09 17:00:00 
  .....     |        ......
```

With a given datetime, my python function looks for the closest day in the table (col0) and returns col1 and col2:

```
from datetime import datetime
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors as cursors
import time

conn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","FOO_DATABASE", cursorclass = cursors.SSCursor )

def foo(x):
    c.execute("SELECT start_time, end_time FROM staff WHERE Date >= %s  ORDER BY Date  LIMIT 1", (x,))
    results = c.fetchone()
    col1 = results[0]
    col2 = results[1]
    return col1, col2


#Date_time to look
date_time = datetime.strptime('2017-01-01 12:22:00', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

#The loop
start = time.time()
for i in range(60000):
    c = conn.cursor()
    foo(date_time)
    c.close()

end = time.time()
print round((end - start), 2)
```

For 60 000 loops (which is not so much regarding my program) it runs in 21 seconds.

I look forward to  improve this.

**EDIT 1**

Well, just created an index on the "day" column and it goes 2 times faster, 9.13 seconds.
Hope to improve it because it's not sufficient for my application

**EDIT 2**

To make in clearer the loop passes 60,000 different values, the use of the fixed value was for illustration purpose.

In my production scheduling algorithm I have to test many combinations of schedules and thus find out the working times for a given datetime. If the date is not in my table (a weekend for example) the function will return the next opening day working time range. Hope it's clear!

Comment: If it's purely on performance, opening and closing the connection are going to make a difference.  Try commenting out the foo(date_time) bit and see how long that takes.

Comment: Commenting out foo(date_time) make the loop compute in 0.45 seconds

Comment: Am I missing something as your loop passes the same datetime 60,000 times? What's the point of repeated values? What do you mean by *closest day*? Relative to what?

Comment: Question edited to make it clearer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try prepared statement:

```
    from datetime import datetime
    import MySQLdb
    import MySQLdb.cursors as cursors
    import time

    conn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","FOO_DATABASE", cursorclass = cursors.SSCursor )
    #Date_time to look
    date_time = datetime.strptime('2017-01-01 12:22:00', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    #The loop
    start = time.time()

    c = conn.cursor()
    for i in range(60000):
        c.execute("SELECT start_time, end_time FROM staff WHERE Date >= :p_date ORDER BY Date  LIMIT 1", {"p_date", date_time})
        col1, col2 = c.fetchone()
    c.close()

    end = time.time()
    print(round((end - start), 2))
```

Or even better try to write sql that you will get all 60k rows by one sql execution.

Comment: Thanks a lot but I have the following error : "AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'prepare'. Removing "cursorclass = cursors.SSCursor " doesn't help

Comment: Yes, looks like mysql does not have prepared statements. But in this answer says that parametrized execution will be execute same way on driver leve. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947750/does-python-support-mysql-prepared-statements Did fix answer.

Comment: Just to give an overall context, I'm building a scheduling planning. I don't know in advance which values will go in the function. It depends on how the planning shows up in my algorithm

Comment: :) our answers crossed ! Thanks a lot I will have a look