# Sqlite INSERT unix time

Tags: python, sqlite

Maybe someone can advise, how to correctly add code which returns epoch time. In MySQL I use following string, but this does not work with sqlite

```
 query = 'INSERT INTO '+ADS1115tableName+('(dateTime, usUnits, `interval`, ads_ch1, ads_ch2, ads_ch3, ads_ch4, pin1, pin2) VALUES(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),  %i, %i, %.3f, %.3f, %.3f, %.3f, %.1f, %.1f)' %( units, gap, Voltage[0], Voltage[1], Voltage[2], Voltage[3], button1.value, button2.value ))
```

Where I can place `strftime('%s', 'now')` in my query?

Many Thanks

Andrej

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First, I would separate the query template from the code that populates query parameters.
2. Then it would be easy to make the template "parametrized" as well and replace: `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` with `strftime('%s', 'now')`

P.S. It's a best practice to use parametrized queries instead of direct interpolation of values [such as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947750/does-python-support-mysql-prepared-statements/1947993#1947993)