# Binding a list of strings to an IN clause

Tags: python, sqlite, list, binding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python list in sql query as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283645/python-list-in-sql-query-as-parameter)

Consider this (using [apsw](http://apsw.googlecode.com/svn/publish/index.html) here):

```
s = ["A", "B", "C"]
c.execute("SELECT foo.y FROM foo WHERE foo.x in (?)", (s, ))
```

This doesn't work, because a binding parameter cannot be a list. I want to bind a list of strings to `?`. I know how to build the appropriate query-string manually, but I wonder if there is a way to do this with bindings.

Comment: Have you tried `tuple(s)` instead of `(s, )`?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283645/python-list-in-sql-query-as-parameter will help.

Comment: @gimel: Thank you, I didn't see that one. @KennyTM: That raises `too many bindings`.

Comment: You'll need the correct number of ? in your query string, as many as elements in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Going with the multiple question marks idea by Fabian, how about

```
c.execute("SELECT foo.y FROM foo WHERE foo.x in (%s)" % ', '.join('?' * len(s)), s)
```

Comment: I should've checked gimel's link before answering.  It's the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem around 4 years ago, and then I found out it was impossible to bind lists to sql (i was using mssql server and ODBC provider, but also considered direct sql calls)
In my case i was just building the queries manually and it was efficient. In case you have a very long list of values you will have to create another table, populate it in runtime and join with it in your sql.