# Escaping chars in Python and sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a python script that reads raw movie text files into an sqlite database.

I use re.escape(title) to add escape chars into the strings to make them db safe before executing the inserts.

Why does this not work:

```
In [16]: c.execute("UPDATE movies SET rating = '8.7' WHERE name='\'Allo\ \'Allo\!\"\ \(1982\)'")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- OperationalError                       Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/rajat/Dropbox/amdb/<ipython console> in <module>()

OperationalError: near "Allo": syntax error
```

Yet this works (removed \' in two places) :

```
In [17]: c.execute("UPDATE movies SET rating = '8.7' WHERE name='Allo\ Allo\!\"\ \(1982\)'") Out[17]: <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x9666e90>
```

I can't figure it out. I also can't ditch those leading quotes because they're actually part of the movie title.
Thank you.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. Literally. You should be using parameters, like this:

```
c.execute("UPDATE movies SET rating = ? WHERE name = ?", (8.7, "'Allo 'Allo! (1982)"))
```

Like that, you won't need to do *any* quoting at all and (if those values are coming from anyone untrusted) you'll be 100% safe (here) from SQL injection attacks too.

Comment: absolutely.  quoting and escaping are last-resource kludges.  if parameters are available, use them _always_

Comment: BTW, the same idea works just as well for pretty much every other database worth the name out there too, and in virtually every other practical programming language. *Everyone* does it this way because it is *right*.

Comment: Awesome thanks Donal. All working well now. I'd used similar methods with RoR, where it is well documented. But hours of searching for "python sqlite escape characters" yielded nothing. python docs leave a lot to be desired. Thanks Donal and all

Comment: @rajat: No idea what I searched for (might have even just been `python sqlite example` and working through the top hit) since I've had a browser crash since then. :-/

Comment: Note that these parameters only work for values. They don't work for column names, for instance. Quoting might be a kludge but it's still necessary sometimes.

Comment: Wouldn't this throw an error when a user submits something in double quotes ? Something like - 'He said,"yo who goes there? "' (without the single quotes?)

Comment: Here's a [nice trick](http://stackoverflow.com/a/283801/3491991) for passing a list of strings into a parameter

Comment: It's usually an indication of something terribly wrong if your database interface is passing user-supplied names as table or column identifiers. (Or you are making a real expert-only interface, in which case you're very much not doing ordinary database code!)

Comment: How do I generalize this? For example `c.execute(f"UPDATE results SET code = ? SET job = ? SET description = ?, ({code},{job_title},{description})")` returns the error `OperationalError: near "SET": syntax error` - so clearly I'm missing something.

Answer (score 15):

> I use re.escape(title) to add escape
>   chars into the strings to make them db
>   safe

Note that `re.escape` makes a string **re**-safe -- nothing to do with making it **db** safe.  Rather, as @Donal says, what you need is the *parameter substitution* concept of the Python DB API -- **that** makes things "db safe" as you need.

Answer (score 10):

SQLite doesn't support backslash escape sequences.  Apostrophes in string literals are indicated by doubling them: `'''Allo ''Allo! (1982)'`.

But, like Donal said, you should be using parameters.

Answer (score -7):

I've one simple tip you could use to handle this problem:
When your SQL statement string has single quote:', then you could use double quote to enclose your statement string. And when your SQL statement string has double quotes:", then you could use single quote:" to enclose your statement string.
E.g.

```
sqlString="UPDATE movies SET rating = '8.7' WHERE name='Allo Allo !' (1982 )"
c.execute(sqlString)
```

Or,

```
sqlString='UPDATE movies SET rating = "8.7" WHERE name="Allo Allo !" (1982 )'
c.execute(sqlString)
```

This solution works for me in Python environment.

Comment: And what if the value you are search has a double-quote in it?  Use parameters as per Donal's answer. Or escape (only as a last resort) against the delimiting character (single quote in the OP question; or double-quotes in your example)

Comment: colminator, my string has no double-quote. If your string has double-quote, just use "\"".

Comment: You have a static example. In the real world - the WHERE clause would be dynamic. Dynamic content can not be trusted to have delimiter conflicts without escaping - whether you use single or double-quotes.

Comment: Hi Clock, it's been some years since you've posted this. Have you since come to understand why this answer is dangerous?

Comment: @aggregate1166877 Thanks! Yes, you are right that this workaround could cause sql database injection attack risk. I'll add this reminding in my answer.