# Using variable combining LIKE and %s% in SQLite and Python

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

Using:

- Python3
- SQLite
- TKinter

I am currently trying to create a function to search for a keyword in a database, but as soon as I try to combine it with TKinter, it seems to fail.

Here are the relevant lines:
(I tried it in a lot of different ways, those 3 lines below seem to work with variables, but not with the input from TKinter, so I thought they might actually work, if I edit them a little.

The problem I got is, that I'm not experienced in TKinter and SQLite yet and worked with those 2 for about 3 days yet.

```
def searcher(column):

    #Getting input from user (TKinter)
    keyword = tk.Entry(self)
    keyword.pack()

    #Assigning the input to a variable
    kword = keyword.get()

    c.execute("SELECT * FROM my_lib WHERE {kappa} LIKE {%goal%}".format(kappa=column, goal=kword))
    #c.execute("SELECT * FROM my_lib WHERE "+column+"=?", (kword,))
    #c.execute("SELECT * FROM my_lib WHERE {} LIKE '%kword%'".format(column))
```

I want to check if any of the data CONTAINS the keyword, so basically:

`k_word in column_data`

and not

`column_data == k_word`

**My question is:**

Is there a way to take the user input *(by TKinter)* and search in the database *(SQLite)* and check, if any data in the database contains the keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQLite docs explain that you can use `?` as a placeholder in the query string, which allows you so substitute in a tuple of values. They also advise *against* ever assembling a full query using variables with Python's string operations (explained below):

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM my_lib WHERE ? LIKE ?", (column, '%'+kword+'%'))
```

You can see above that I concatenated the `%` with `kword`, which will get substituted into the second `?`. This also is secure, meaning it will protect against SQL Injection attacks if needed.

Docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Related posts: [Escaping chars in Python and sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220005/escaping-chars-in-python-and-sqlite)

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
kword = "%"+kword+"%"
c.execute("SELECT * FROM my_lib WHERE kappa LIKE '%s'" % kword)
```