# Python's sqlite3 module: get query with escaped parameters

Tags: python, sqlite, python-db-api

The [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/sqlite3.html) module allows one to use parameter substitution for queries like so:

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("create table lang (name, first_appeared)")
cur.execute("insert into lang values (?, ?)", ("C", 1972))
```

I'd like to be able to get the "post-substitution" query string. In the example above that would be:

```
"insert into lang values ('C', '1972')"
```

Can it be done? There doesn't seem to be a documented means of doing this, but I'd settle for undocumented.

Comment: Are you "forced" to use post-substitution? If not: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3220028/13871725

Comment: I want the results of the substitution. If I have to actually execute the query to get it, that's fine, but my goal is to get the post-substitution string.

Comment: What problem are you going to solve by having this string?

Comment: I'm solving the problem of getting the post-substitution query string!

Comment: IMHO I think you should use format strings for this one.

Comment: I want exactly what the database would execute given the parameters, so Python string substitution isn't going to work.

Comment: There is no string "substitution". Your query is parsed to a _prepared statement_ first and then during request parameters are "bound" to that prepared statement https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html as a result no string exists with "substituted" values. Python just hides that in a simplified API

Comment: @mkrieger1 - yes, `set_trace_callback` seems to do the trick. Many thanks! I'll accept this as an answer if you post it.