# Enclose each element in a string-tuple with quotes

Tags: python

I need to query to a database and filter on a `where link in (....)`. The issue is the `(...)` since that "tuple" is dynamic. If I do it like this:

```py
input_links = get_links() # [<link1>,...]
query = f"SELECT * from myTable where link in {tuple(input_links)}
```

that works fine unless `input_links` contains one link then the last part becomes `(link1,)` thus breaking the query.

I've tried using

```py
input_links = get_links() # [<link1>,...]
link_tpl = f'({",".join(input_links)})'
query = f"SELECT * from myTable where link in {link_tpl}
```

but that encloses the entire argument in the tuple in one quote e.g `('link1,link2,link3')` instead of `('link1','link2','link3')`.

I know I can just do an

```py
if len(input_links)==1:
   query = f"SELECT * from myTable where link={input_links[0]}"
else:
   f"SELECT * from myTable where link in {tuple(input_links)}
```

but it just bothers me that I cannot have it as one statement.

Comment: ```f'(",".join(input_links))'``` should be ```(",".join(input_links))'```

Comment: True, thats a typo in the question (it was formatted correctly in the code)

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using a prepared statement for this? In addition to the safety benefits, it seems like it would be easier in this case

Comment: What do you mean by "prepared statement"?

Comment: @CutePoison Check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had this headache a few weeks back. Ended up doing something like this:

```
'(%s)' % ', '.join(map(repr, input_links))
```

Output:

```
   ...: input_links = [link1]
   ...: print('(%s)' % ', '.join(map(repr, input_links)))
   ...:
   ...: input_links = [link1, link2]
   ...: print('(%s)' % ', '.join(map(repr, input_links)))
(link1)
(link1, link2)
```

Based from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6082234/6759844) answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can map each item in `input_links` to a string formatter:

```
query = f'''SELECT * from myTable where link=({', '.join(map("'{}'".format, input_links))})'''
```

Comment: Upvote!  Excellent use of `map`; learned something new.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. Assuming the links as `'1','2'...`:

```
l=['1','2']
def check_tup(l):
    k=','.join(f"'{i}'" for i in l)
    return f'({k})'
print(f"SELECT * from myTable where link in {check_tup(l)}")
```

Outputs:

```
SELECT * from myTable where link in ('1','2')
```

If `l=['1']`:

```
SELECT * from myTable where link in ('1')
```