# Add quotes to every list element

Tags: python

I'm very new to python. I need a simple and clear script to add quotes to every list elements. Let me explain more. Here is the my code.

```
parameters = ['a', 'b', 'c']
query = "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar IN (%s)" % (', '.join(parameters))
```

I want to use this to query. But result is invalid query. Here is the result.

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar IN (a, b, c, d)
```

I want to like this:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

How to add quotes while joining elements.

Comment: This is the **WRONG WAY** to use parameters in SQL, Blender warned about "SQL injection", but not strongly enough IMO. You should ask a new question about how to properly use parameters in SQL

Comment: I know. Thank you for advise. I found very secure way.

Comment: @Zeck What is the secure way?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

A naive solution would be to iterate over your `parameters` list and append quotes to the beginning and end of each element:

```
(', '.join('"' + item + '"' for item in parameters))
```

Note: this is vulnerable to SQL injection (whether coincidental or deliberate). A better solution is to let the database quote and insert these values:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar IN (%s)" % ','.join('?' * len(params))
cursor.execute(query, params)
```

It's easier to read and handles quoting properly.

Comment: `["'" + item + "'" for item in parameters]` would give him single quotes, which is what he asked for.

Comment: to nit pick, you don't need the list [] here: (', '.join('"' + item + '"' for item in parameters))

Comment: @Blender No, a list DOESN'T get spat out of that expression. The generator makes the items as `string.join` asks for them, then they can immediately get garbage collected. With a list comprehension, they all get generated and stored, then join iterates over the list, and garbage collection on them can't occur until join is done with the whole list.

Comment: @agf, thanks for the info. I didn't know that generator expressions and list comprehensions were different in that regard. I will update my answer.

Comment: @Blender Take a look at my answer for an even simpler, more efficient version (posted long after yours).

Comment: When I do this, I get an error as the ? and not replaced by the variables. Why is this? I'm on Python 3.6

Comment: @EsbenEickhardt: What database driver are you using?

Comment: @Blender I am using psycopg2.connect, and I dont give it a database driver as input, so it must handle it in the background.

Comment: @EsbenEickhardt: `psycopg2` uses `%s` (for everything, not just strings) instead of `?`.

Answer (score 12):

For simple parameters, the following should work:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar IN %s" % repr(tuple(map(str,parameters)))
```

This may break down when the parameter names themselves include quotes, as the escaping rules are different.

Comment: This script generates invalid query.

Comment: It generates "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar IN ('a', 'b', 'c')", which matches what was asked for, and works (at least with the one database I tried, namely sqlite3).

Comment: Sorry I'm using PostgreSQL. It shows me SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar IN ((u'a', u'b', u'c', u'd')) this. An invalid query.

Comment: Ah, your parameter array has unicode characters not strings as you asked.  I've modified the example to convert to strings.  In any case, if you have complex strings you want to do considerably more than simply add quotes.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. Sorry for give you down rate. Feel sorry.

Answer (score 9):

As you asked it, use this:

```
parameters = ['a', 'b', 'c']
', '.join(map(lambda x: "'" + x + "'", parameters))
```

Since you're creating an SQL query, please use your database library's features regarding input sanitation ([example for mysqldb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/python-mysql-with-variables/775399#775399)).  You don't want to end up with an issue like [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: `(lambda x: "'" + x + "'", parameters)` would give him single quotes, which is what he asked for.

Comment: @robert: A good generator expression using builtins will almost always be faster than using map on a user-defined function on CPython, because it will happen almost entirely in C. It's also more readable and the Pythonic way to do it. Much love for little Bobby Tables though.

Comment: @agf: more readable, yes; faster? Not on Python 2. Compare `timeit(lambda: ', '.join(map(lambda x: "'" + x + "'", parameters)))` and `timeit(lambda: ', '.join("'" + x + "'" for x in parameters))`. The `map()` version is 15-20% faster on Python 2.7.1+/Ubuntu 11.04 64-bit. The generator version is about 8% faster on Python 3.2/ditto.

Comment: @Chris-Morgan: I'm on Python 2.7.1 32-bit on 64-bit Windows 7 and the the generator version is 20% faster. Edit: Running it a second time, the generator version is the same speed, but the map version is much faster.

Comment: @Chris-Morgan: And the version from my answer below, `timeit(lambda: "', '".join(parameters))`, is about 5x faster than `timeit(lambda: ', '.join(map(lambda x: "'" + x + "'", parameters)))`, although that's comparing apples to oranges. It seems to me map/lambda must somehow be doing the string concatenation differently?

Answer (score 3):

In general (ignoring SQL)

```
In [3]: print(' '.join('"%s"' % x for x in ['a', 'b']))                                                                                                                                              
"a" "b"
```

Answer (score 0):

if your list looks like

```
lst = ['abc', '123', 'xyz']
str_row = "( '"+"','".join(map(str, lst))+"')"
print(str_row)
```

output will be

```
( 'abc','123','xyz')
```