# Passing lists or tuples as arguments in django raw sql

Tags: sql, django, list, tuples

I have a list and want to pass thru django raw sql.

Here is my list

`region = ['US','CA','UK']`

I am pasting a part of raw sql here.

`results = MMCode.objects.raw('select assigner, assignee from mm_code where date between %s and %s and country_code in %s',[fromdate,todate,region])`

Now it gives the below error, when i execute it in django python shell

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1412, in __iter__
query = iter(self.query)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 73, in __iter__
self._execute_query()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 87, in _execute_query
self.cursor.execute(self.sql, self.params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 15, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 86, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 166, in execute
self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 35, in defaulterrorhandler
raise errorclass, errorvalue
DatabaseError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1")
```

I have tried by passing the tuple also but there is no use. Can some one help me.

Thanks
Vikram

Comment: Can you give us the sql query string your app is trying to execute?

Comment: This is my sql query which it was executing correctly and it is retrieving results. `select assigner, assignee from mm_code where date between '2011-07-21' and '2011-07-31' and country_code in ('US','UK','CA')` I have tried so many combinations but always giving error :-(

Comment: Are you sure that your framework builds the same query?

Comment: Yes.. the above query executes in Django Shell up to date condition but when I give the country_code condition, its giving errors. Please help me

Comment: can some one answer this question

Comment: Try using(changed char [ to ( ): MMCode.objects.raw('select assigner, assignee from mm_code where date between %s and %s and country_code in %s',(fromdate,todate,region))

Comment: Using a tuple '()' over a list '[]' wouldn't make any difference. In fact the official [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw) uses a list for passing parameters.

Comment: Paste your `models.py`

Comment: I'm trying to make the same thing work but with id:s. For now I have to divide all the queries and run them one by one. Not a massive job but it doesnt feel quite DRY.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Casting the list to a tuple does work in Postgres, although the same code fails under sqlite3 with `DatabaseError: near "?": syntax error` so it seems this is backend-specific. Your line of code would become:

`results = MMCode.objects.raw('select assigner, assignee from mm_code where date between %s and %s and country_code in %s',[fromdate,todate,tuple(region)])`

I tested this on a clean Django 1.5.1 project with the following in bar/models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class MMCode(models.Model):
    assigner = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    assignee = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField()
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=2)
```

then at the shell:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> from bar.models import MMCode
>>> 
>>> regions = ['US', 'CA', 'UK']
>>> fromdate = date.today()
>>> todate = date.today()
>>> 
>>> results = MMCode.objects.raw('select id, assigner, assignee from bar_mmcode where date between %s and %s and country_code in %s',[fromdate,todate,tuple(regions)])
>>> list(results)
[]
```

(note that the query line is changed slightly here, to use the default table name created by Django, and to include the `id` column in the output so that the ORM doesn't complain)

Answer (score 39):

For PostgreSQL at least, a list/tuple parameter is converted into an array in SQL, e.g.

```
ARRAY['US', 'CA', 'UK']
```

When this is inserted into the given query, it results in invalid SQL -

```
SELECT assigner, assignee FROM mm_code
WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-02-01' AND '2014-02-05'
AND country_code IN ARRAY['US', 'CA', 'UK']
```

However, the 'in' clause in SQL is logically equivalent to -

```
SELECT assigner, assignee FROM mm_code
WHERE date BETWEEN %s AND %s
AND country_code = ANY(%s)
```

... and when this query is filled with the parameters, the resulting SQL is valid and works -

```
SELECT assigner, assignee FROM mm_code
WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-02-01' AND '2014-02-05'
AND country_code = ANY(ARRAY['US', 'CA', 'UK'])
```

I'm not sure if this works in the other databases though, and whether or not this changes how the query is planned.

Comment: I can confirm this solution works in 2022 with PostgreSQL 10 and Django 3.2

Comment: If anyone like me looks for the opposite it works by _negating_: `NOT country_code = ANY(ARRAY['US', 'CA', 'UK'])`

Answer (score 4):

This is not a great solution, because you must make sure your "region" values are correctly [escaped for SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw). However, this is the only thing I could get to work with Sqlite:

```
sql = ('select assigner, assignee from mm_code '
    'where date between %%s and %%s and country_code in %s' % (tuple(region),))
results = MMCode.objects.raw(sql, [fromdate,todate])
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into exactly this problem today. Django has changed (we now have `RawSQL()` and friends!), but the general solution is still the same.

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/283801/532513 the general idea is to explicitly add the same numbers of placeholders to your SQL string as there are elements in your `region` array.

Your code would then look like this:

```
sql = 'select assigner, assignee from mm_code where date between %s and %s and country_code in ({0})'\
      .format(','.join([%s] * len(region)))
results = MMCode.objects.raw(sql, [fromdate,todate] + region)
```

Your sql string would then first become `... between %s and %s and country_code in (%s, %s, %s) ...` and your params would be effectively `[fromdate, todate, 'US', 'CA', 'UK']`. This way, you allow the database backend to correctly escape and potentially encode each of the country codes.

Answer (score -2):

Well i'm not against raw sql but you can use: 
`MMCode.objects.filter(country_code__in=region, date__range=[fromdate,todate])`

hope this helps.

Comment: Well my query is very big one I have just pasted a subquery here. So ORM is not useful in my case and I am not good at ORM :-)

Comment: Since your raw sql worked in django shell, it probably has to do with your list. Try to debug and find the sql query formed at run time.

Comment: @Pannu the issue was not what SQL query to write, issue is to pass arguments to raw sql, ORM may not be perfomant in some cases.