# Django filter multiple columns with a list of tuples

Tags: sql, django-models

I have a simple model with 2 fields:

```
class Simple(Model)
    class Meta:
        index_together = True

    a = IntField()
    b = IntField()
```

I would like to generate an SQL query for tuples of values for `a,b`.
e.g.

```
select * 
from SimpleModel 
where (a,b) in ((1,1), (4,8), ...)
```

I know how to create something like:

```
select * 
from SimpleModel 
where ((a = 1 and b = 1) or (a = 4 and b = 8))
```

Which is logically the same, but I think my DB has a problem when the number of possible values is very big (I am using Postgresql), also the query itself is much longer so it's heavier on the network, and probably harder for it to analyze and read it correctly (i.e. use the composite index in this case).

So, the question is, can I get Django to create the query in the first form?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but only* using the `where` parameter of `extra`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra

Something like this should do:

```
Simple.objects.extra(where=['(a,b) in %s' % your_list])
```

*If you create a custom database type you should be able to define custom operators, so... might be able to work around it. I'll google a bit :)

Comment: Note that as of Django 1.8 support for .extra is being phased out

Comment: @MrDBA: it's not going to be phased out in the near future as the current development still supports it. Personally I strongly feel they should reconsider the decision for removal as there will always be cases where it's useful to support custom queries at a lower level.

Answer (score 13):

@Wolph answer is correct but I would do it this way

```
tuple_of_tuples = ((1,1), (4,8))
Simple.objects.extra(where=['(a,b) in %s'], params=[tuple_of_tuples])
```

Check here about passing a tuple and not a list

[Passing lists or tuples as arguments in django raw sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895051/passing-lists-or-tuples-as-arguments-in-django-raw-sql)

For the `params` I quote from Django docs
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra

> **params**
>
> The **where** parameter described above may use standard Python database
>   string placeholders — **'%s'** to indicate parameters the database engine
>   should automatically quote. The **params** argument is a list of any extra
>   parameters to be substituted.
>
> Example:
>
> `Entry.objects.extra(where=['headline=%s'], params=['Lennon'])`
>
> Always use **params** instead of embedding values directly into **where** because
>   **params** will ensure values are quoted correctly according to your
>   particular backend. For example, quotes will be escaped correctly.