# Django filter on list of column values

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I'm using Django 3.2 and Postgres 13.

I have a simple model:

```py
from django.db import models


class Member(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey("Group", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=["user", "group"], name="unique_user_group_tuple"
            )
        ]
```

The important info here is the `UniqueConstraint`, which also creates a unique index.

Let's say I have a list of `(user_id, group_id)` tuples:

```py
member_tuples = [(1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 4)]
```

I would like to retrieve all existing `Member` objects matching these tuples, **while using the index**. In PG, I would write:

```sql
SELECT * from members where (user_id, group_id) in ((1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 4));
```

My question is: how to get something similar in Django ? Obviously, my main concern is to keep calling the `unique_user_group_tuple` index, to avoid a sequential scan

For now, the best solution I found is to do:

```py
filters = Q()
for user_id, group_id in member_tuples:
    filters |= Q(user_id=user_id, group_id=group_id)

existing_members = Member.objects.filter(filters)
```

which translates to

```sql
SELECT * from members WHERE (issue_id = 1 AND group_id = 1) OR (issue_id = 2 AND group_id = 1) OR (issue_id = 2 AND group_id = 4);
```

This also queries the index, but it does not creates the query I expect.

So, I try to achieve 2 different things:

- find a way to annotate a record, e.g. return something like: `SELECT (user_id, group_id) as member_tuple FROM member`
- use a collection of records in a `WHERE` clause: `WHERE something IN ((1,1), (2,1) (2,4));`

Comment: Does this answer help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23991090/django-filter-multiple-columns-with-a-list-of-tuples/41717889#41717889?

Comment: Thanks, even though I tried to look for existing questions, I missed this one. This does solve my issue, the only problem is, it uses `extra`, which is clearly not recommended by the Django doc. Thanks anyway, I'll look more into it

Comment: There actually is a open Django issue on this subject: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/33015