# Django, Postgres DB, raw queries, and bounded IN parameters

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2, django-orm

I need to run a raw query and the `WHERE` clause is an `IN`.

```
select
    o.*,
from
    ff_ooo as o
left join
    ff_ooostatus s on o.id = s.ooo_id
left join
    ff_rrrr r on s.rrrr_id=r.id
where
    o.id in %s
group by
    o.id
having
    r.due_date = max(r.due_date)
```

I execute it using

```
return list(Ooo.objects.raw(
    sql,
    params=(ooo_ids,)
))
```

`ooo_ids` is an array of integers.

The resulting SQL fails with this error:

> ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "ARRAY" LINE 13:     o.id in
>   ARRAY[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]

I see that the Postgres ORM code is making the `IN` statement bound parameter into an `ARRAY[]`. but postgres DB does not like it.

How do I properly bind an integer array to an `IN` clause in a Django raw SQL query against a postgres DB?

Comment: For Postgresql this answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22008870/3246440

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing lists or tuples as arguments in django raw sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895051/passing-lists-or-tuples-as-arguments-in-django-raw-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `list()` pass parameters as `tuple()` like this:

```
return list(Ooo.objects.raw(
    sql,
    params=(tuple(ooo_ids),)
))
```