# Python MySQLdb/mysqlclient: bind a named set (or tuple or list) as parameter

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python, named-parameters

**Background: Not much documentation on MySQLdb Connector**

Maybe I'm looking in the wrong places, but there's not much documentation about Python's `MySQLdb` family of connectors. Perhaps [PEP249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) is meant to do the job. Oracle's MySQL/Python connector seems to have much better [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/), but at the moment I'm working with [mysqlclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient) (the 3.x version of MySQLdb, which wraps around the C connector).

**Named Parameters in MySQLdb: working for single values**

After much searching, I stumbled upon beautiful syntax for binding named parameters, so long as they are a single value. For instance (made-up query to simplify the case):

```
query = """
        SELECT... 
        WHERE 
             name = %(name)s AND
             gender = %(gender)s
        """
parameters = {'name': name, 'gender': gender}
cursor.execute(query, parameters)
```

This properly escapes the parameters. Terrific.

**Named Parameters in MySQLdb: how to use iterables?**

Now I'd like to use a set, list or tuple to build queries with `IN`. Something like:

```
query = """
        SELECT... 
        WHERE 
        gender = %(gender)s AND
        name IN %(nameset)s
        """
```

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283645/python-list-in-sql-query-as-parameter) but that query doesn't use named parameters (the placeholder is named, but not the iterable).

What am I missing? Would someone know the magic syntax to make this work?

I see in the MySQLdb code that `paramstyle` is set to `format` rather than `pyformat`, but `pyformat` does work for single values.

To clarify,

- I am not interested in an answer that just builds a string like `('sophie', 'jane', 'chloe')` and concatenates it to the query. I need bound parameters to guarantee proper escaping.
- I am also not interested in concatenating a join that uses `db.escape_string()`, although I may end up going that route if nothing else works.

What I'm really after is a clean idiom that binds named iterable parameters, if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

Don't love answering my own question, but it's been a day...

Having looked inside the MySQLdb code, it looks like I won't get my wish. The quoting function will always add one set of quotes too many.

This is where I've ended up (the fallback option I had mentioned):

```
idset = ('Chloe', 'Zoe', "Noe';drip dautobus")

quoted_ids = [mdb.escape_string(identifier).decode('utf-8') for identifier in idset]
sql_idset = "('" + "', '".join(quoted_ids) + "')"

query = """
        SELECT ...
            FROM ...
            JOIN ...
            WHERE
              someid = %(someid)s AND
              namae IN """ + sql_idset

parameters = {'someid': someid}
cursor.execute(query, parameters)
```

Only one of the parameters is bound. The set in the `IN` clause is pre-quoted.
Not my favorite thing to have to do, but at least each value is run through the MySQLdb quoting function in order to quote any potentially harmful stuff.

The `decode` is there because `escape_string` prepares a byte string, but the `query` being built with the bound parameter `someid` is a string. Maybe there is an easier way. If you find one, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to express it specifically in MySQLdb but it just works out of the box with the MySQL connector library (version: 1.4.4, MySQL 5.7.x) as suggested in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40737575/3469555):

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM test WHERE id in %(l)s', {'l': (1,2,3)})
```

If MySQLdb messes it up then I suggest acquiring direct cursor somehow.