# One line to check if string or list, then convert to list in Python

Tags: python

Suppose I have an object `a` that can either be a string (like `'hello'` or `'hello there'`) or a list (like `['hello', 'goodbye']`). I need to check if `a` is a string or list. If it's a string, then I want to convert it to a one element list (so convert `'hello there'` to `['hello there']`). If it's a list, then I want to leave it alone as a list.

Is there a Pythonic one-line piece of code to do this? I know I can do:

```
if isinstance(a, str):
    a = [a]
```

But I'm wondering if there's a more direct, more Pythonic one-liner to do this.

Comment: You way is already very pythonic - it is clear and concise. If you are interested, here is another way: `s = (isinstance(s, str) and [s]) or s`

Answer (score 40):

You can use a ternary operator:

```
a = [a] if isinstance(a, str) else a
```

Answer (score 9):

```
[a] if isinstance(a, str) else a
```

Answer (score 5):

This works for string and a list/tuple/set of strings. Additionally, it converts a `None` to an empty list.

```py
from typing import List, Optional, Set, Tuple, Union

def ensure_list(s: Optional[Union[str, List[str], Tuple[str], Set[str]]]) -> List[str]:
    # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56641168/
    return s if isinstance(s, list) else list(s) if isinstance(s, (tuple, set)) else [] if s is None else [s]
```

Test:

```py
>>> ensure_list('abc')
['abc']
>>> ensure_list(['a', 'bb', 'ccc'])
['a', 'bb', 'ccc']
>>> ensure_list(('a', 'bb', 'ccc'))
['a', 'bb', 'ccc']
>>> ensure_list({'a', 'bb', 'ccc'})
['ccc', 'a', 'bb']
>>> ensure_list(None)
[]
>>> ensure_list('')
['']
```

If you don't want to convert a `None` to an empty list, remove `else [] if s is None`.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the other option rather than `isinstance`:

```
b = [a] if type(a) is str else a
print(b)
```

And it's possible to do the other way around:

```
b = a if type(a) is list else [a]
```

And even make it a little ore robust:

```
b = a if type(a) in [list, tuple] else [a]
```

if you deal with tuples as well.

Comment: `isinstance` is recommended because it properly handles inheritance. It can also handle multiple types with e.g. `b = a if isinstance(a, (list, tuple)) else [a]`. Also, `==` rather than `is` would be better here. Finally, note that you can "do the other way around" with `isinstance` as well with a simple `not`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Thanks for the info about `isinstance`. As for `isinstance` vs `type` - I prefer the readability. A class derived from str, tuple or list? I used none of these. Of course if someone used them, he would definitely do `isinstance`.