# Use python list IN postgresql query

Tags: python, postgresql

My question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283645/python-list-in-sql-query-as-parameter) but I have strings instead of integers in my list.

My `python list`:

```
list = ['a', 'b'] #number of items varies from 1 to 6
```

I want to use this list in Postgres query like this

```
select * from sample where sub in ('a', 'b');
```

I can use `tuple(list)` to get `('a', 'b')`, this is not useful when length of my list became one. I am struggling to find a way to convert
`['a']` to `('a')` 
`['a', 'b']` to `('a', 'b')`
I tried

```
In[91]: myquery = "select * from sample where sub in (%s)" % ",".join(map(str,list))
In[92]: myquery
Out[92]: 'select * from sample where sub in (a,b,c)'
```

But postgres expects

```
select * from sample where sub in ('a', 'b');
```

Comment: Postgres expects *single* quotes for strings: `select * from sample where sub in ('a','b','c')`. Double quotes are for identifiers.

Comment: Thanks for that, I just copy pasted here. I will correct that.

Comment: `"select * from sample where sub in (%s)" % ",".join(map(repr, lst))` or `q = "select * from sample where sub in (%s)" % ",".join(map("'{}'".format, lst))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use psycopg2 and it will handle this for you correctly for all sorts of edge cases you haven't thought of yet.  For your specific problem see **http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#adapt-tuple**

Comment: Thanks! `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM sample WHERE sub = ANY(%s);", (list,))` worked :) Man page: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#lists-adaptation

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used python's bindings to postgresql so I don't know if it is possible to bind a python list (or a tuple) to a placeholder in a query, but if it is, then you could use the `ANY` operator as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM sample WHERE sub = ANY (%s);
```

and bind the list the only parameter.

Answer (score -4):

Try ",".join(["'{0}'".format(s) for s in list]).

Comment: Thanks! It gives `"'a','b'"`, not `('a', 'b')`