# Python looping List Values in a SQL Query as a Parameter

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sql-server

I am having issues looping a list of values that has `ids` to pass them as parameters into a SQL query using pyodbc connection. I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283645/python-list-in-sql-query-as-parameter) 
which seems to have lot good information, but I haven't seen an answer that loops through the list and replaces `ids` in each iteration.

Here is my list,

```
Allids = [201,202,203,204,205,206,207]
```

I would like to do something like this,

```
for i in Allids:
    cu.execute('select my_var1, my_var2, my_var2 from testdata.dbo.tbl where id = 'i'')
```

I get an error saying that `][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'i' to data type int.`

Is it possible do this way? or convert the list into tuples and follow different methods? Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `cu.execute('select my_var1, my_var2, my_var2 from testdata.dbo.tbl where id = \'%d\'' %i )`

Comment: @ COLDSPEED nice, this worked, thank you. Could you give a brief explanation? Or direct me to any sources.

Comment: No, problem. Just be careful with user input data. SQL injection is real.