# Python list in psql query as a parameter

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I tried the following code in order to run my query using hadm list 
       inside the query but at the end.

```
hadm = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
placeholder= '?'
placeholders= ','.join(placeholder for unused in hadm)

sql_lab = """SELECT admissions.hadm_id as hadm_id, min(charttime) as first_lab
FROM mimic2v26.labevents JOIN mimic2v26.admissions using(subject_id) 
WHERE admissions.hadm_id in (%s) AND
charttime - admit_dt > interval '-48 hours'
GROUP BY admissions.hadm_id"""%placeholders

cur.execute(sql_lab,hadm)
```

I got the following error:

```
ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-156-2263cc2076d2> in <module>()
      7 charttime - admit_dt > interval '-48 hours'
      8 GROUP BY admissions.hadm_id"""%placeholders
----> 9 cur.execute(sql_lab,hadm)

ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near ","
LINE 3: WHERE admissions.hadm_id in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?...
                                  ^
```

Comment: What are you expecting `placeholders` to output?

Comment: @rahlf23 I got the answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283645/python-list-in-sql-query-as-parameter , but  I am still getting an error

Comment: `placeholder= "'?'"`

Comment: @Wen I still get an error:  DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "?"

Comment: @rahlf23  by (%s) I mean hadm, in the other word "WHERE admissions.hadm_id in (hadm)"