# python list containing ID in sql query as parameter

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have an ID list

```
id = [339, 344, 340, 343, 345, 342, 341]
```

already select as in the way in this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283645/python-list-in-sql-query-as-parameter), 
this is the code

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM news_tb where id IN ({})".format(",".join([str(i) for i in hasil])))
```

but the results are in sequence

```
[(339, '..'), (340, '..'), (341, '..'), (342, '..'), (343, '..'), (344, '..'), (345, '..')]
```

I want the data output to be sequential according to the id in the list. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

results = sorted(results, key=lambda x: id.index(x[0]))

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your results are in `results`,

```
r_dict = dict([r[0],r[1:]] for r in results)
ordered_results = [tuple([i]+list(r_dict[i])) for i in id]
print(ordered_results)
```

will print the desired list.

Comment: there is an error like ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 5; 2 is required

Comment: What does your `results` actually look like?

Comment: the result is like this, because it is too long [(339, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), (340, 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h.'), .... , (345, 'ab', 'cd', 'awdaw', 'awd')]

Comment: That would have been nice to put in the question.

Comment: yes, sorry i will fix it in the next question. Thank you very much