# TypeError not all arguments converted during string formatting, but no string is being evaluated

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am making a db query in the following way:

```
class AllData(APIView):

def get(self, request, ids=None):
    followers = self.request.GET
    follower_ids = []
    for x in followers:
        follower_ids.append(followers[x])

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT authapi_user.id, authapi_user.first_name, authapi_tweet.tweet_text 
                        FROM authapi_tweet 
                        INNER JOIN authapi_user 
                        ON authapi_user.id = authapi_tweet.author_id 
                        WHERE authapi_tweet.author_id=? 
                        ORDER BY created_on DESC", follower_ids)
        table = cursor.fetchall()
        return Response(table)
```

I get the following error:

> Not all arguments converted during string formatting

From what I've found online that happens when evaluating a string but the list being passed into the query in the WHERE clause is a list of int, such as [1,2,3].

How is this variable supposed to be formatted when the value it's being compared to in the query is also an int in the database?

I've also tested this code while placing a static number in the WHERE clause so I know the issue is with that specific line of inserting a variable.

Comment: You only have one parameter in the query so you should only be passing one value, not a list with many.

Comment: @shawn How could I change this to be able to check a list of values in that condition?

Comment: For a list of values, you need to construct an `IN` expression in SQL, with a different parameter placeholder for each value. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/283801/696808) provides a good example of how to do that. Beware that almost every other answer on that question except the accepted one is an SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

In sqlite, you can use syntax like `WHERE id in (1,3,5,7)` to search a list (not a python list!). I have not found a way to parametrize that.

One solution is to build the query using string format method; a simple example:

```
ids = [2,4,6]
idlist = ','.join(str(i) for i in ids)
query = "SELECT * from t1 WHERE id in ({0})".format(ids)
db.execute(query)
```

BUT WAIT: this will expose the code the sql injection. Assuming the ids in the code are all integers, there are any number of ways to create a valid, safe "idlist" of only integers before creating/submitting the query.