# Use Python List in the SQL as parameter

Tags: python, sql

I am referring to [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283645/python-list-in-sql-query-as-parameter)

what if I have to pass some extra parameter along with `list` in the query. Suppose I want to pass the location as well

```
`placeholder= '?' # For SQLite. See DBAPI paramstyle.
 placeholders= ', '.join(placeholder for unused in l)
 query= 'SELECT name FROM students WHERE id IN (%s) and location= %(location)s' % placeholders
 cursor.execute(query, {'location' : 'canada', 'desired_list' : list_of_ids })
```

how to convert `list` into `tuple` for using in sql query? Thanks

Comment: `tuple(list_of_ids)`

Comment: When the list size is 1, tuple ends up like `(1,)` , which fails while executing the query

Comment: For a completely different reason though.

Comment: How about `','.join(list_of_ids)`, in case of a single list or tuple element, it'll print `(1)` instead of `(1,)`. `join` however, works with string elements only, so if your `id's` are integer, you could use - `','.join(map(str, list_of_ids))` instead.