# How To Pass Mutiple Values As Parameter In Cursor.Execute Method OF HANA Python Connector

Tags: python, hana

I am using HANA Python Connector's Cursor.execute(sql,hanaparams) method, the parameters to this method are sql statement and hanaparams.My query is like this.

"SELECT * FROM TABLE WHRE COLUMN1 IN(?)" and My PARAMETES ARE VALUE1 ,VALUE2; LIKE LIST/TUPLE;

I am unable to retrieve resultset, Whereas when i run this in HANA with Query and Input Parameters Hard Coded in ,it runs perfectly fine

I am following this tutorial [https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/hana-clients-python.ht](https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/hana-clients-python.html)ml

Any pointers how should i Pass multiple values in Params

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python list in sql query as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283645/python-list-in-sql-query-as-parameter)

Comment: @astenx , thanks for your help, appreciate your input; this is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Something simple like this seems to work just fine. Count of `?` must be equal to count of parameters you have. In your case it takes only `VALUE1`.

```
from hdbcli import dbapi

conn = dbapi.connect(
    key='HDBKEY'
)

cursor = conn.cursor()
parameters = [11, "2020-12-24"]
params = '?,'*len(parameters)
params2 = params[0:-1]
sql_command2 = f"SELECT {params2} FROM DUMMY;"
cursor.execute(sql_command2, parameters)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    for col in row:
        print ("%s" % col, end=" ")
        print (" ")
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

So instead of `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN1 IN(?)` it should be `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN1 IN(?, ?)`

Comment: Thanks For Reply @Reinis Verbelis, The Input Param  Can become Val1,Val2,Val3. So let us say Input param is List.  In this case how do we pass Input Params

Comment: To be honest I am not sure, but you could make up the SQL query to include as many `?` as there are items in the list. Made an edit in my example. Seems to work fine

Comment: Thanks For Reply @Reinis Verbelis, I tried same approach where i concatenated params with LIST_AGG function and passed that as Input Param , unfortunately it is not working.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Maybe you can post you code.