How to pass list of integers as arguments for django's raw SQL, without formatting string
I'm struggling to figure out how to pass list of integer as arguments for Django's raw SQL without using f-string method.
I have tried a simple method of
def raw_query(self) -> str:
    return """select * from table where some_id in %s"""

and call with (where ids are list of integer that I already wrap them as tuple)
tupled_ids = tuple(ids)
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(self.raw_query(), [ids])

Apparently, this wraps the argument with single quote, making them '(1,2,3)' instead of (1,2,3). Thus, syntax error.
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "'(1,2,3)'"

I've also tried
def raw_query(self) -> str:
    return """select * from table where some_id = any(%s)"""

also give me similar error
django.db.utils.DataError: malformed array literal: "(1,2,3,4,5)"
LINE 2: ...om table where some_id = any('(1,2,3...`

I've also tried with named params
def raw_query(self) -> str:
    return """select * from table where some_id in %(ids)s"""

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(sql=self.raw_query(),
                           params={
                               "ids": tuple(ids)
                           })

Still produce syntax error.
It looks like Django keeps wrapping my list with quote. I feel like there must have been an obvious mistake but I can't really figure it out.
There are other solutions that suggest to generate a place holder and use f-string to format the raw SQL statement, such as.
def raw_query(self, ids: list[int]) -> str:
    placeholder = ','.join(['%s'] * len(ids))
    return f"""select * from table where some_id in ({placeholders})"""

^ This works
Still, I am wondering if there's a better solution as I don't want to string format my SQL statement.
I'm using Python 3.12 and Django 5.0.3
I cannot use an ORM as the actual query is more complex than this, and I'll have to union two queries together and do annotation afterward which an ORM doesn't support.
There's a similar question like Passing lists or tuples as arguments in django raw sql which is a possible duplicate question. However, it does not answer this question as I provided in example, why it doesn't work and some of the suggested solution required you to do string-formatting. I'm actively looking for answer that does not required you to format-string, if possible.

Apparently this is dependent on the db driver, not all of them support it. The main one that does is Postgres with psycopg2 https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adapt-tuple This answer has a workaround for other dbs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/283801/202168

Why using raw queries instead of Django's ORM?

What you're doing at the end (','.join(['%s'] * len(ids))) is exactly what Django is doing internally as well. See: this and this. If you're hesitant with that you might as well completely use the ORM

@willeM_VanOnsem The actual query is more complex than this, and need to union queries. Unfortunately, ORM doesn’t support doing annotations after union query.

@AbdulAzizBarkat oh well, I guess that works. Initially, I didn't want to do it as it prones to the usual SQL injection. Looks like that will have to be the way.
Thank you for providing the actual source code as reference.

Some context to the duplicate: That question has various answers that work on certain database backends and also has the approach that worked for you. The answer to this particular question is "It depends on the backend and the generic way to do it is the one you're already using". Which basically means you just have to do what you're already doing. That kind of fragments information away from the duplicate target which is the canonical for the case of Django.

@AbdulAzizBarkat I see. I was unsure with the approach which is why I put up the question. With your answer, at least I now know that what I'm doing is already an accepted approach to the said problem.
Thank you for your explanation, I really apprecaite it :D
